# Grails Spring Security plugin: Getting 302 for Ajax Request for timedout Session

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

We are using Spring Security plugin version 1.2.7.3 with Grails 2.2.1. 
In my `Config.groovy`, I do:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl = "/mylogin/authAjax"
```

thinking that, when there is an Ajax request, Spring Security will invoke `authAjax()` in `MyloginController` if the User's HttpSession has timed out.

As per doc, I ensure that the header `X-Requested-With` with value `XMLHttpRequest` is in the Ajax request so the plugin knows it is an Ajax request.

My expectation is `authAjax()` will be invoked and I can make that return a 401, so the UI knows it needs to pop up another login screen.

However, instead of the `authAjax()` getting invoked, a 302 is returned to the UI with the location field set to `http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/mycontroller/authAjax`

This means I'll have to put in something very hackey on my UI, check for a 302 and check the location field and then make the User re-login.  I would much prefer to have a 401 returned.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a million.

Comment: Could be that your authAjax url is not permitted for everyone.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this issue, I found it was simply down to the chainMap rules.
I have my REST api sitting under the '/api/' url so my chainMap looks like this:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/api/**',         filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'], // Stateless API
    [pattern: '/**',             filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'] // Traditional, session based accesses.
]
```

The last 2 lines are the important bit; '/api/**' is secured by the Spring Security REST plugin which is a stateless connection (i.e. each request carries the authentication token). The '/**' rule covers everything else which requires a stateful session (the non-REST activity).
The stateless REST request will return 402 if the token has expired or is invalid in any way and the stateful non-rest will return 302 and send your browser round a loop.

Get those rules in the right order and you should be fine.